# Issue with Nginx redirecting to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, subdomain, passenger

So, I have a domain: coolapp.com Now I want to make it so I can have two subdomains, such as game.coolapp.com and sports.coolapp.com. I have two server configurations in the nginx config as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sports.coolapp.com;
    location / {
        root /home/deployer/Sports/current/public;
        index  index.php;
    }
    passenger_enabled on;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name game.coolapp.com;
    location / {
        root /home/deployer/Game/current/public;
        index  index.php;
    }
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

For some reason, both of these domains are redirecting to the 'sports' app. They SHOULD each by redirecting to their own application, but are interfering with each other.

I am running the Sports app via passenger, with something like 'passenger start --port 80', and I'm running the second app with 'passenger start --port 81'. Should I be running these with different arguments, or what exactly is causing the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not quite clear to me. I am making the following assumptions in my answer.

1. You are running 3 apps all on Phusion with Nginx.

Nginx configuration is pretty straight forward. Probably you have configured nginx.conf properly because you main app is working.

The next thing you should do is read the phusion passenger doc on how to run Rails on subdomain. Reading https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app will give you a lot of insight. I recommend you read the entire doc.

I think there is a problem in the way you have configured your nginx.conf and how you are starting you phusion passenger (BTW I think you do not even have to start the phusion passenger explicitly and that NGINX should take care of that)

In your nginx configuration you are listening to port 80 and in your phusion passenger command you are asking it to listen to port 81 and 82. Change you nginx configuration to read like (BTW it is better to use sites-available & site-enabled for this)

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name sports.coolapp.com;
        root /home/deployer/Sports/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }

server {

        listen 80;
        server_name games.coolapp.com;
        root /home/deployer/Sports/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
```

I hope you have configured your subdomains properly. You should double check that as well.

Save changes. Restart Nginx and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realize that nginx manages Passenger, thanks a lot, will definitely be reading the doc over again!